# MVC4: Preload application without having access to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I want to have my MVC application to warm up the application after it is being restarted, so the next initial loading will cost almost no time.

The problem is that I do not have the access to the server computer IIS.

I have searched of how to do it, and I found this:

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>
```

But this code requires access to the server computer.

How can I do it only with my application and web.config?